# Laravel migrate database database using artisan with new columns

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-artisan

I am using laravel and I am trying to do another migration but the table already exists so it is throwing the following error:

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already 
  exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists
```

I've added this line into the migration file:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

This is the full file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ConfideSetupUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        // Creates the users table
        Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('confirmation_code');
            $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->boolean('confirmed')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        // Creates password reminders table
        Schema::create('password_reminders', function ($table) {
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('password_reminders');
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rollback the migration and then run it again:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

And then:

```
php artisan migrate
```

**Attention** in your case this will delete all data from the table since it will drop `users` and `password` reminder and then recreate it.

The alternative is to create a new migration:

```
php artisan migrate:make users_add_soft_deletes
```

Put this in there:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

And run `php artisan migrate` to apply the new migration

Comment: ok I see, will the alternative solution allow me to specify where in the table I want this go to?

Comment: Yes, if you're using MySQL you can do `$table->softDeletes()->after('remember_token');`